# System.loadLibrary failing on java 1.6 but working on java 1.5

Tags: java, java-native-interface, aix

I have ran into a peculiar problem on AIX 6.1 and SLES 11 . I am trying to load a `so` file in Java using `System.loadLibrary()` call. Below is sample program:

```
public class jniTest
{ 

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      try
      {
         System.loadLibrary("libSample.so");
         System.out.println("Loaded!!!");
      }
      catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
      {
         System.out.println("unsatisfiedlinkerror");
      }
}
```

When I compile this piece of code with Java 1.5 it works properly. But when I compile it with Java 1.6 it says `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I don't understand how I could possibly be getting this error. The way I am running is:

```
javac jniTest.java

java -Djava.library.path=. jniTest
```

The `so` file is place in the current directory from where I am running the code.
Before this, things I have tried:

1. giving the absolute path - didn't work
2. using `Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary()` - didn't work

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you compile it with 1.5 but run it with 1.6 ?

Comment: Did you check the message of the UnsatisfiedLinkError? It should give some hint on what went wrong. Maybe the library is found but can't be loaded by Java 6.

Comment: What's the result of `ldd libSample.so` under SLES ? I guess there is no ldd in AIX. A possible reason is libSample.so having a dependency to a JSE 1.5 library.

Comment: dump -Tv libSample.so will show its dependencies and search path.

Comment: tried ldd libSample.so on AIX, i got this as the output

Comment: <p> /usr/lib/libc_r.a(shr.o)  
 /unix
 /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
 /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
 /usr/lib/libcfg.a(shr.o)
 /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr.o)

Comment: @CoreyStup: its a nice command, showed all the external dependencies. But there are few unresolved dependencies.     
[49]    0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref              .. _ZdlPv

[50]    0x00000000    undef      IMP     DS EXTref              .. 
_Znam

[52]    0x00000000    undef      IMP     PR EXTref              .. __gxx_personality_v0

What does these references mean? No where in the code i am using anything like this... :(

Comment: gxx_personality screams of gcc/g++ stuff.   Was your shared library built with gcc?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're supposed to have the "`.so`" extension when using JNI.  Try with just `System.loadLibrary("libSample");`

Comment: Hi Jim, i tried it but no luck its still saying UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: This is late but for anyone reading this. You must use the platform name for `loadLibrary` i.e. in this case it should be `Sample`. The function will add `lib` and ´.so` if you're running linux or `.dll` if you're running windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what Jim said: you don't need the .so extention or the 'lib' part of the file.  This should work(at least, it works for me in 1.6):

```
  try
  {
     System.loadLibrary("Sample");
     System.out.println("Loaded!!!");
  }
  catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
  {
     System.out.println("unsatisfiedlinkerror");
  }
```

Comment: Hi rm5248, tried this one also, but didnt work for me. I am on AIX 6.1. But the same piece of code worked for java 1.5 version. Its not working for 1.6 version of java.

Answer (score 0):

The first three things I think of:

1. Make sure the library is on the java lib path (You've done this)
2. Make sure you're using `System.loadLibrary()` correctly. If your library is called "libSample.so", the call should be `System.loadLibrary("Sample")`. (This has been suggested in other answers)
3. Consider that there may be an issue with the library under OpenJDK, and that's the Java VM you're using. Run the command `java -version` and if part of the response is something like `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_0-b11)`, try installing the official Sun JDK and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Rob, I am using official sun jdk,

Comment: # /usr/java6/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260-20071123_01)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260-20071121_15015 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20071121_015015_bHdSMR
JIT  - r9_20071121_1330
GC   - 20071031_AA)
JCL  - 20071118_01

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that your native functions in Java do not line up with the functions in the library.  There is a very clearly defined naming convention for JNI functions.
For example, if you have a function in java that's supposed to call a c/c++ library function:

```
package my.packagename;

public class Test {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Sample");
    }

    public native void testJNI(int arg1);
}
```

The corresponding function in c or c++ MUST be (Assuming your package name is "com.packagename"):

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_packagename_Test_testJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint arg1) {
     // ... code here
}
```

The reason I went through that is if the function names do not match, an UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown.